# Fetching the last item of nested items with a selector

Tags: jquery, css

I thought this should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure it out! I'm trying get the last item with a class of `.simple` in each parent.

```
<ul>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item (this one)</li>
  <li class="group">
    <ul>
       <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
       <li class="simple">Simple Item (this one)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with `:last`

```
$('ul > li.simple:last').css('color', 'red');
```

But it fetches the very last item that matches.

How can I fetch each last `.simple`?

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hav497t1/48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()`

```js
$("ul").each(function(){
  $("> li.simple" , this).last().css("color" , "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
  <li class="simple">Simple Item (this one)</li>
  <li class="group">
    <ul>
       <li class="simple">Simple Item</li>
       <li class="simple">Simple Item (this one)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As [@cheesyman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15121332/cheesyman) mentioned in the comment below

> As of jQuery 3.4, the [:last pseudo-class is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/). Remove it from
> your selectors and filter the results later using .last().

Comment: The `:last` pseudo selector [has been deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) since jQuery 3.4. Instead should use the `.last()` method. `$("> li.simple" , this).last().css("color" , "red");`